# parsing and constructing three lists of equal length python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse an xml block as follows:

```
<table>
     <table>
      <elem key="val1">abc</elem>
      <elem key="val2">xyz</elem>
     </table>
   <table>
      <elem key="val2">def</elem>
      <elem key="val3">pqr</elem>
   </table>
    <table>
      <elem key="val1">ghi</elem>
      <elem key="val3">tuv</elem>
   </table>
 </table>
```

Now, I have written following code snippet to parse this and capture values:

```
                        for elem in item:
                            if elem.attrib["key"] == "val1":
                                l1.append(elem.text)

                            elif elem.attrib["key"] == "val2":
                                l2.append(elem.text)

                            elif elem.attrib["key"] == "val3":
                                l3.append(elem.text)
```

What I want is these three lists of equal length as follows:

```
  l1 = ['abc', '', 'ghi']
  l2 = ['xyz', 'def', '']
  l3 = ['', 'pqr', 'tuv']
```

I am not getting any clue regarding how to do this.

Comment: Update your code so it contains the definition of item

Comment: `l1.append(elem.txt if elem.attribe["key"] == "val1" else "")`, etc.

Comment: @chepner I wonder with this if I will be able to accommodate multiple values here i.e. val1, val2 etc.

Comment: Ah, I misread the original code slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that might work. What it does is first collect the table values into dictionaries like `{'val1': 'abc', 'val2': 'xyz', 'val3': ''}` from [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys), which will initialize `''` for values that were not found. Then we can get these values from doing a nested list comprehension over `values`.

**Demo:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
  <table>
    <table>
      <elem key="val1">abc</elem>
      <elem key="val2">xyz</elem>
    </table>
    <table>
      <elem key="val2">def</elem>
      <elem key="val3">pqr</elem>
    </table>
    <table>
      <elem key="val1">ghi</elem>
      <elem key="val3">tuv</elem>
    </table>
  </table>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

values = ("val1", "val2", "val3")

tables = []
for child in root:
    table = dict.fromkeys(values, '')

    for item in child:
        value = item.attrib["key"]
        table[value] = item.text

   tables.append(table)

print([[table[val] for table in tables] for val in values])
```

**Output:**

```
[['abc', '', 'ghi'], ['xyz', 'def', ''], ['', 'pqr', 'tuv']]
```

Then we can unpack the result into three lists `l1`, `l2`, and `l3`:

```
result = [[table[val] for table in tables] for val in values]

l1, l2, l3 = result

print(l1)
# ['abc', '', 'ghi']

print(l2)
# ['xyz', 'def', '']

print(l3)
# ['', 'pqr', 'tuv']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

I found it quite useful when trying to parse xml